# PDO prepare fails

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
// BETA KEYS //
function getBetaKey( $key ) {

    global $pdo;

    $get = $pdo -> prepare( "SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."betakeys WHERE key = :key" );
    $get -> execute( array( ':key' => $key ) );
    $get -> setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    return $get -> fetch( );

}
```

Fails with this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''base_betakeys' WHERE 'key' = '{randomKey}'

When I use this **`** in the prepare statment like this:

```
    // BETA KEYS //
function getBetaKey( $key ) {

    global $pdo;

    $get = $pdo -> prepare( "SELECT * FROM `".DB_PREFIX."betakeys` WHERE `key` = :key" );
    $get -> execute( array( ':key' => $key ) );
    $get -> setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    return $get -> fetch( );

}
```

It works, what is the problem ?

Comment: Ouch... `global $pdo;`?? Please consider writing `function getBetaKey(PDO $pdo, $key)` <-- whatever the function needs to work, it should be an argument. Never rely on globals being defined/being what you need them to be. As a bonus: function arguments can enforce some type-safety through type-hinting

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php follow this link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`key` is a reserved word in MYSQL.

You can escape the word by wrapping it in `` `backticks` `` as you've done.

See more of them [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).